# how do I deploy the marketplace-portlet or importing marketplace-portlet dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I'm trying to complete [The Official Documentation for Hooks in Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-a-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-10-en). About halfway down that page, there is a note.

```
Note: If the Liferay server prints the following message to your console,
the Marketplace Portlet and Portal Compatibility Hook must not already be
deployed on your server.

"Plugin example-hook requires marketplace-portlet, portal-compat-hook"
```

I do get this message, so I attempt to follow the instructions:

```
You can fork and clone Liferay’s liferay-plugins project from GitHub, checkout the   
respective branch and/or tag, and deploy each plugin. You can install the Plugins
SDK in Liferay IDE and import each plugin and deploy them. Here is information on
each of the plugins:

Marketplace Portlet (marketplace-portlet) - is available at liferay-
plugins/portlets/marketplace-portlet.

Portal Compatibility Hook (portal-compat-hook) - is available at liferay-
plugins/hooks/portal-compat-hook.
```

This is as much information as I can find about setting up the marketplace-portlet.

So I clone, and add the whole repo as an existing Eclipse project, not a liferay project. I check the checkbox for look for nested projects, find and add the marketplace portlet and hit finished. Then I assume to fix the build path by changing `plugin-master` to `portal-6.2.x`

As you can see, this solves more than half of the missing .jars, but the ones that are still missing claim the build path is the same, so they are missing from the repo, or need to be built. I have no idea which.

So, how do I deploy the marketplace-portlet?

[image: build issues]

Comment: Which version of Liferay and which appserver are you using? Are you using a bundle (e.g. Liferay preinstalled on tomcat) or do you install on your own appserver? The bundle typically come with marketplace installed, so it should be a non-issue - no need to compile it by yourself

Comment: Liferay 6.2 and the Liferay packaged version of Tomcat. In reaction to your point about it coming bundled I deleted the server folder, removed it from Eclipse, extracted the original .zip, and whalla no error message. It seems small, but if you post a "Re-install the server" answer, I'll accept it. It did solve my problem. This is not the first problem solved by re-extracting the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, combining our comments into an answer:

"Have you tried installing fresh again?" ;)

To make it worth a real answer: The typical bundle installation comes fully runnable (the installation instructions are: unzip, start tomcat) and contains everything you need - especially in a development environment.

If you use Liferay IDE or the EE equivalent Developer Studio (both based on eclipse), they even know how to unzip the server themselves (a necessity if you're developing/redeploying ext plugins).

Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened repeatedly. Something about a bad deploy could cause Liferay to remove its own Marketplace portlet*.

Rather than re-install each time, I grabbed the Marketplace Portlet.war from [Liferay's Get Marketplace Portlet page](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/download) and would deploy it using the Liferay Control Panel.

*: I don't have an exact steps to reproduce, sorry.